# Maximun Capacities of Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server

I would like to know the maximum capacities of Ubuntu server 20.04

- Supported architectures
- Supported CPU cores
- Maximum supported RAM

Grateful

Jose

Answer (score 4):

Given the way the question is asked, I am curious to know how much research you have done prior to visiting this site. A lot of the information you seek can be found on Ubuntu.com.

That said …

**Supported architectures**

⇢ x64 / ARM / Power / s390x / others (if you’re willing to do the work)

**Supported CPU cores**

⇢ All of them. There is no CPU in existence with more cores than a modern Linux kernel can handle.

**Maximum supported RAM**

⇢ 16EB (though many enterprise motherboards top out at 2TB per CPU socket)

Comment: thanks for your anwser

Answer (score 1):

here are some references which relate to your multi-faceted question:

[Ram](https://askubuntu.com/a/557713/307670)

[Architectures](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SupportedArchitectures)

[Cores](https://askubuntu.com/a/158606/307670)

Comment: thanks for your anwser